# Are there any open mathematical puzzles?

Tags: soft-question, puzzle, big-list

Are there any (mathematical) puzzles that are still unresolved? I only mean questions that are accessible to and understandable by the complete layman and which have not been solved, despite serious efforts, by mathematicians (or laymen for that matter)?

My question does not ask for puzzles that have been shown to have either no solution or multiple solutions (or have been shown to be ambiguously formulated).

Comment: I think you'll have to be more specific on what you mean by complete layman.

Comment: Game theory puzzle: Can white force a win in chess?

Comment: [Goldbach's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach's_conjecture)?

Comment: I think this might be of interest to you: http://youtu.be/JPhqhZvXlhQ

Comment: @VincentPfenninger Which also leads to the  "incomplete layman".

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/q/100265/12357

Comment: @vadim123 Care to turn your highly popular comment into an answer?

Comment: @aufkag, why bother?  There's plenty of answers already, and everything's community wiki so there aren't any internet points at stake.

Comment: @vadim123 That's true (and I didn't agree with that), but still, it would allow chess to flow to its "rank" in the popular vote.

Comment: I was about to remark that this is genref because of the [many lists of unsolved problems in mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsolved_problems_in_mathematics). But then I noticed that the title specifically says 'puzzles'. But then I'm not sure what the difference is between 'puzzles' and mathematical problems in general. I mean I know it when I see it but...

Comment: @Mitch The key words in the question are "the complete layman". Problems/puzzles that are completely understandable by, say, 85%(?) of the general population, i.e. without them going _blank_. So, I figure, the moving sofa problem is quite perfect, whereas the Callatz conjecture is already in danger territory. But that's only the intended interpretation and possibly not made clear in the question. My bad.

Comment: My fourth-grade class had a unit on the Collatz conjecture where we each picked our own number and iterated the system until it converged.

Comment: @vadim123 First, can White force a **draw** in chess?

Comment: I've come to feel that a better question would be, "Why are there _so many_ such open questions, and why is it so _dang_ easy to come up with them?"  Just as two, the Goldbach or the Collatz conjectures _seem_ like such dumb little ideas for questions, until you try to settle the matters.  (And Goldbach's been around almost 3/4 as long as Fermat's (last theorem) conjecture.)

Comment: http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387975061

Answer (score 141):

The [sofa problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_sofa_problem).

From Wikipedia:

> It asks for the rigid two-dimensional shape of largest area $A$ that
>   can be maneuvered through an L-shaped planar region with legs of unit
>   width. The area $A$ thus obtained is referred to as the sofa constant.
>   The exact value of the sofa constant is an open problem.

[image]

Author of the picture: Claudio Rocchini, see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hammersley_sofa_animated.gif)

Comment: Very cute graphic there!

Comment: +1 Nice, very practical and understandable. I'm quite surprised by the seemingly large difference between lower and upper bounds provided by Wikipedia.

Comment: This seems extremely solvable. Is it a joke or a very fitting answer to an odd question?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe No, it seems that this is really an open problem.

Comment: Cool animation!

Comment: Is it known that $A$ is attained, or is it just a $\sup$?

Comment: @dtldarek Wikipedia :) StefanSmith: It is an attained limit. The link contains further references which discuss this problem. aufkag: there are no physical constraints, the problem can be formulated in purely geometrical terms.

Comment: @O.L. This is [a link](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~suh/gerver-moving_sofa.pdf) to the Gerver paper. Quickly scanning it, I think it conjectures that the solution proposed (Fig. 2 on p. 268) is uniquely maximal.

Comment: _"It would be really useful to know before you buy a piece of furniture whether it's actually going to fit up the stairs or around the corner."_ – From _Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency_, Douglas Adams

Comment: @PålGD If my memory serves me correctly, Dirk Gently actually solved this problem with the novel solution of "door".

Comment: @O.L. Sure, it's gone now. I didn't mean to leave it there, just too little time for everything.

Comment: Ironically, the solution which "cuts corners" turns out to be optimal.

Comment: Silly question I know, but what would be the maximal area of a rectangular thing that would fit there?

Comment: @Pranasas I'll bet it is $1$.

Comment: That object in the graphic is a sofa?

Comment: @O.L. I was very wrong.

Comment: I remember in high school thinking up this problem, and solving it, in the case that the sofa is a rectangle.  In the general case, though...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most of the arcs on the sofa shown in the gif aren't even circles, but rather more complicated curves.

Answer (score 100):

The [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) seems to fit the bill.

Consider the function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ (here $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$) given by

$$f(n) = \begin{cases}
\frac{n}{2} &\ \text{if}\ n\ \text{is even,}\\
&\\
3n+1 &\ \text{if}\ n\ \text{is odd.}
\end{cases}$$

The Collatz conjecture states that, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^k(n) = 1$ where $f^k = \underbrace{f\circ f\circ \dots \circ f \circ f}_{k\ \text{times}}$. That is, for any positive integer, repeated application of the function $f$ will eventually lead to $1$.

---

Of course, this conjecture can be stated without the need to refer to the function $f$, but rather the rules of a game as follows.

1. Pick a positive integer.
2. If the number is even, divide it by two. If the number is odd, multiply by three and add one.
3. If the number from step 2 is $1$, stop. Otherwise, repeat step 2.

Does the game always finish, no matter what number we begin with?

Comment: What is the importance of this conjecture?

Comment: @TylerHilton: Its ultimate importance is probably unknown, much as the importance of Fermat's Last Theorem was unknown at the time of its writing (but later led to significant advances in number theory). To quote Erdos: "Mathematics is not yet ready for such problems."

Comment: @tylerhilton: Ideally we'd like to understand the dynamics of functions $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ in general.  This is the simplest example where we very much don't -- it's piecewise linear, for goodness's sake!

Comment: @TylerHilton Like a lot of mathematical stuff, it is important because it helps to fight mental obesity.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury: I'm not sure which properties of functions $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ should cause them to be called piecewise-linear, but I'm pretty sure the function considered here (which depends on parity of the argument) does not qualify for that adjective.

Comment: Fair enough.  However, if I take $S = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} [2n - \frac{1}{2}, 2n + \frac{1}{2})$ and $T = \mathbb{R} \setminus S$ then $f$ is the restriction of $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
x/2 & \text{ if } x \in S \\
3x+1 & \text{ if } x \in T \end{cases}$$
(among an endless number of other similar such functions) which I *believe* is considered a piecewise-linear function in common parlance.  (Of course an arbitrary such function won't send $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, so there's some subtlety here.)

Comment: @TylerHilton Probably not what you meant; but trying to find a counter example via brute force methods is one of the biggest credit fountains among BOINC distributed computing projects.  http://boincstats.com/en/stats/projectStatsInfo

Comment: What's important is that it looks true but it can't be proved true (yet). Once we prove that it is true, we might have a new tool that may help us solve other problems.

Answer (score 56):

Frankl's [union-closed sets conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture): if $\mathcal F$ is a nonempty finite collection of nonempty finite sets, and if $X\cup Y\in\mathcal F$ whenever $X,Y\in\mathcal F$, must there be an element which is in more than half the members of $\mathcal F$?

P.S. There is an equivalent form of the conjecture, where the family $\mathcal F$ is permitted to have $\emptyset$ as an element; in this case the condition $\mathcal F\ne\emptyset$ has to be strengthened to $\bigcup\mathcal F\ne\emptyset$, and the conclusion has to be weakened to an element which is in **at least** half the members of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: That's nice, I'd never seen that before.

Comment: Thats crazy that this is open.

Comment: I don't know how easy this would be for a layman to understand.

Comment: I can see a fairly obvious solution to this, actually. At least I think it would prove it...

Comment: @AJMansfield You don't think the fact that it's been open for 30 years rules out a "fairly obvious solution"?

Comment: @PålGD Even if not, I will at least learn some stuff as I attempt to solidify my solution!

Comment: @AJMansfield I have a wonderful proof of this conjecture, but the StackExchange comment length is too small for me to post it here ;-)

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I'm sure something along the lines of the following would be clear enough with a little dialogue (but someone else can word it more elegantly): "An online store has a variety of combo-deals. And for any two combos they have, they also offer a combo with all of those items together. Must it be the case that some item is in at least half of the combos? Mathematicians don't know."

Comment: @MarkS. That's pretty good. +1 if I could vote.

Comment: Ps., there is also a [graph formulation of the union-closed sets conjecture](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4175) (arxiv).

Comment: @PålGD Thanks, that's interesting. Not too surprising, seeing as a family of subsets of a set is more or less the same thing as a bipartite graph. I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 50):

In the spirit of O.L.'s example, I believe that the **[moving needle problem](http://conan777.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/the-moving-needle-problem/)** is still open:

> Given a smoothly embedded copy of $\mathbb{R}$ in
>   $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing $\{ (x,0,0) \ | \ x \in (-\infty,-C] \cup [C, \infty) \}$, is it always possible to continuously slide a unit
>   length needle lying on the ray $(-\infty, -C]$ to the ray $[C, \infty)$, while keeping the head and tail of the needle on the curve
>   throughout the process?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason why we're embedding $\mathbb R$ is three dimensional space, rather than n-dimensional space for $n>1$?

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld I guess not. It just makes the problem easier to visualize. When I heard it stated the first time, it was stated for $\mathbf R^2$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought maybe it was easier in some dimensions than others.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld You're welcome. Maybe it is. Well, for $n=1$ it is certainly quite obvious. :)

Comment: Anybody volunteering to make an animated picture of this? It seems that [Claudio Rocchini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Rocchini), the maker of the picture in O.L.'s answer, doesn't do requests: "You need a mathematical image? Dont' ask to me! I'm Too Busy."

Comment: @Marie, is the smoothness needed? Is there an example of a non-smooth embedding in which this doesn't work? (Just curious here) editing: Ok, I read the counterexample, sorry.

Comment: If every time (only) one side of the needle is perpendicular with the path, you retain the direction of travel for that side but reverse it for the other side, won't this create a continuous sequence of states that can never repeat, and thus the needle will be guaranteed to traverse through any path?

Comment: @Briguy37 That doesn't work. At least not as stated. Every time you switch direction on a head, it's when the opposite end of the needle becomes perpendicular to the path. However, the converse is not true, the needle can become perpendicular, and have no directions change (sort of a Point of Inflection so to speak). You could include that, but I'm not sure how you can prove that it's non-repeating.

Comment: @Cruncher I think you are speaking of when both sides start or stop being perpendicular at the same time (e.g. a circular section or a hairpin path the width of the needle), which is the tough case that my first comment overlooked.  In those cases, the geometry of the paths before and after the double-perpendicular section or points will allow you up to 2 options for travel without backtracking.  Thus, the real question is if it is possible for both of those choices end in an impasse or not.

Comment: It seems this conjecture is similar to the Kakeya conjecture.

Answer (score 45):

The [lonely runner conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonely_runner_conjecture) is particularly simple; If $k$ runners race around a circular track of length $1$ - all beginning from the same point - at pairwise distinct and constant speeds, then for every runner there will be a time when that runner is a distance of at least $1/k$ from every other runner a.k.a lonely.

The result is known for $k \leq 7$, but a general solution has yet to be discovered.

[image]

<sup>*Image by [Claudio Rocchini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lonely_runner.gif).*</sup>

Answer (score 44):

In [his comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532544/are-there-any-open-mathematical-puzzles#comment1137346_532544), user Vincent Pfenninger referred to a YouTube [video](http://youtu.be/JPhqhZvXlhQ) that, amongst other fascinating, layman accessible puzzles, discusses packing squares problems proposed by Paul Erdős. I thought I'd include it among the answers (as a community wiki).

> How big a square do you need to hold eleven little squares?
>
> [image]
>
> **We don't even *know* if this is the best possible [solution.]**

Which, to me, comes as a complete surprise. :)

Here is the link to [*Erich's Packing Center*](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/index.html) provided in grey below the picture. It contains lots of proposed solutions to packing problems like this one.

Comment: I'm never surprised anymore when a packing problem is open and hard.

Comment: This might be a naive question, but... how do we know there *is* a best possible solution?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal I turned your question into a question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/582263/56801 :)

Answer (score 38):

Existence of [odd perfect numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddPerfectNumber.html). (Numbers which are the sum of their own proper divisors). This one has withstood over 2000 years of effort.

Answer (score 37):

The **twin prime conjecture**: there are infinitely many pairs of primes which are a distance $2$ from each other (like 11 and 13).

Comment: The possibility that $p_{n+1}-p_n \to \infty$ for $n\to\infty$ where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime was not ruled out until Yitang Zhang's result this year (2013).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Indeed! This week, Zhang was awarded the Cole prize for this work.

Answer (score 36):

The [Inscribed Square Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem) seems to fit the bill.

> Draw a non-intersecting loop. Is it possible to find four points on the loop which are the corners of a square?

More precisely, by a non-intersecting loop I mean a Jordan curve.

Comment: The distinction between the cases that have been resolved and the general case is probably not very accessible to a layman.

Comment: @MikeHall: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Does the square have to be contained within the loop in order to satisfy the problem?

Comment: @KeithS: Not at all. Check out the first image in the Wikipedia article I linked to.

Comment: I think that Michael refers to the fact that problem is solved for curves which can be drawn by hand.. How would you explain to a layman what a non-piecewise smooth curve is?

Comment: @N.S.: I think a layman is perfectly capable of drawing a curve with cusps, especially if they are trying to find a curve where the claim doesn't hold.

Comment: A curve with cusps is piecewise smooth.

Comment: @N.S. I was thinking continuous. I see, a non-piecewise smooth curve is probably too hard to construct for a non-mathematician.

Answer (score 28):

Can we cover a unit square with $\dfrac1k \times \dfrac1{k+1}$ rectangles, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Note that the areas sum to $1$ since $\displaystyle \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\dfrac1{k(k+1)} = 1$.

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34145/can-we-cover-the-unit-square-by-these-rectangles) is an MO thread discussing some of the progress on this problem.

Answer (score 24):

What is a winning first move in the game of [Chomp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp)? (The game is known to be a win for the first player, but only by a nonconstructive "strategy-stealing" argument.)

Comment: My guess is there are lots of solved puzzles solved by nonconstructive arguments only. Am I right? (I'm a layman myself, so be gentle.)

Comment: Let's see. (1) Strategy-stealing arguments in combinatorial game theory; Chomp is one example, there are a bunch of others. (2) The [probabilistic method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method) famously used by Paul Erdős to prove the lower bound $R(n,n)\gt2^{n/2}$ for the [Ramsey number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey's_theorem) $R(n,n)$. (3) Paradoxical decompositions using the axiom of choice, like the [Banach-Tarski theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox): a unit ball can be cut into 5 pieces which can be reassembled into 2 unit balls.

Comment: Worth noting that for (1) and (2), these aren’t non-constructive in the formal sense of intuitionistic logic.  For (1), for instance, since it’s a finite game on a finite set, the strategy-stealing argument translates into an explicit, constructively definable strategy: simply enumerate the game tree, enumerate all possible strategies, …

Answer (score 23):

Does there exist a rectangular cuboid such that the width, height, breadth, length of all the diagonals, i.e., the diagonals on each face, and the body diagonal, are all integers?

Comment: What is a cuboid here?  The Wikipedia article says there are non-equivalent definitions in use.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I do not understand your question. Essentially, the question is whether there exists $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\sqrt{b^2 + c^2} \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\sqrt{c^2 + a^2} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} \in \mathbb{Z}$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick#Perfect_cuboid

Comment: Okay, so by "cuboid" you mean "rectangular parallelepiped."

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I am curious to know what you interpreted by "rectangular cuboid".

Comment: Oh, has it always said *rectangular* cuboid there?  Somehow I missed that.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Yes, I made sure to mention the word rectangular.

Comment: A related open problem is whether [4D Euler bricks](http://unsolvedproblems.org/index_files/4DEulerBrick.htm) exist. That is, if we drop the requirement that the space diagonal is integral, then can we find $4$ integers such that the square root of the sum of the squares of any two of them is always an integer?

Comment: @JaycobColeman Thanks. This was something I did not know before.

Answer (score 22):

The *einstein* problem (in german meaning *one stone*). Also known as the *monotile* problem.

> Is there a single tile in the plane which can tile the entire plane but can not tile the plane periodically?

Such a tiling with no requirement on the number of tiles is known as an [aperiodic tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_tiling) and is associated with such famous images as the [penrose tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiles)

[image]

and is closely related to the exciting new field of [quasicrystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicrystal) - crystalline structures which give rise to pure point Bragg diffraction patterns with rotational symmetries which are not possible in classical crystals (so not two, three, four, or six-fold symmetry).

[image: enter link description here]

The full statement of the monotile problem actually needs a few assumptions on what a *tile* is, and what it means for it to tile the plane, as certain versions of the problem have been solved. This is discussed in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.1419v2.pdf) by Socolar and Taylor. But some standard assumptions are that the tile is a connected subspace of the plane homeomorphic to the closed disk and with piecewise linear boundary, and that it can tile the plane if you can rotate and translate the tile in such a way that the union of a set of these transformations covers the plane, and the interior of any two transformed tiles have empty intersection.

For instance, if we allow for disconnected tiles, then the [Socolar-Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socolar%E2%80%93Taylor_tile) tile is a monotile.

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: This link may provide some information: http://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.10798 may have settled this question.

Answer (score 17):

[Goldbach's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture).

There are numerous [unsolved problems in number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsolved_problems_in_mathematics#Number_theory_.28general.29).

Answer (score 17):

Here are two more problems I'd like to mention.

> - Does there exist an odd positive integer $n$ (in base 10) satisfying:
>     $$\begin{array}
>   & \text{i})\space n \gt 1 \\
>   \text{ii})\space n \space \text{is a square} \\
>   \text{iii})\space \text{The only digits of}\space n \space \text{are} \space 0 \space \text{and} \space 1. \\
>   \end{array}$$
>
> > I've been playing with this on and off for 10 years with no success!
> >     $\mathbf {Note}$: There are no such integers less than $10^{50}$.

---

> - Find 3 integers $x$,$y$ and $z$ such that $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 33$.

Comment: Wrote a program to rip through the second one (though I'm sure I'm not the first). at least one of z, y, z is not in the range [-650, 650] but the range is still growing

Comment: $x,y,z$ are positive? (you wrote integers)

Comment: @Elimination No, otherwise it would be a very easy problem.

Comment: @Cruncher: For $x^3+y^3+z^3=33$, one of the $x,y,z$ is not even in the range [$-10^{13},10^{13}$]. See table [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1565427/4781).

Comment: **Update**: The latter question has been solved by [Andrew Booker](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maarb/papers/cubesv1.pdf).  The same question with $42$ in place of $33$ remains open.

Comment: Now also solved for 42:  https://phys.org/news/2019-09-sum-cubes-solvedusing-real-life.html .

Answer (score 9):

While this is not a puzzle per se, the (traditional) game of [Reversi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi) is still mathematically unsolved, as are other games that are partially solved. You can see a small list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solved_game#Solved_games).

Comment: The game has been solved for the first player, for all board sizes smaller than the 8x8 grid on which the game is traditionally played. You are right that 8x8 does remain unsolved.

Answer (score 9):

[Gilbreath's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbreath%27s_conjecture) is an unsolved problem related to primes which is as accessible to the layman as the Goldbach conjecture and twin prime conjecture, if not more so. It says that if we write out the prime numbers in order

$2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, ...$

then take the absolute values of the differences (often called the absolute difference) between consecutive terms,

$1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, ...$

and now do the same to the resulting values, then to those values, and so on to infinity i.e.

$1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, ...$

$1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, ...$

$1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, ...$

$1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, ...$

$1, 2, 0, 0, 2, ...$

the first term is always $1$. A simple observation utilized by Andrew Odlyzko to verify the conjecture for the first $3.4 \times 10^{11}$ differences is that if a sequence begins with $1$ and continues with only $0$ and $2$ for the next $n$ terms, then the next $n$ iterated differences must also begin with $1$, since the absolute difference between any combination of $0$ and $2$ is also $0$ or $2$, and the absolute difference between $1$ and either $0$ or $2$ is necessarily equal to $1$. Kyle Sturgill-Simon gives a nice exposition of the problem written specifically for the layman [here](http://www.carroll.edu/library/thesisArchive/Sturgill-Simon_2012final.pdf).

Precisely the same conjecture has been made for the [practical numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number), which have other significant analogies with prime numbers as well (see link). For intuition's sake the practical numbers can be seen as complementary to the primes in the sense that, whereas a prime number has no prime factors less than itself, a practical number typically has many prime factors which are small in comparison with the number itself. As a consequence, small multiples of practical numbers are also practical. In particular, if $n$ is practical and $1\leq m\leq 2n$, then $nm$ is practical. They begin:

$1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 30, 32, 36, 40, 42, 48, 54, ...$

Answer (score 4):

Wolfram's ["New Kind of Science"](http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/toc.html) book on [cellular automata](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CellularAutomaton.html) had a [large accompanying list of open problems](http://www.wolframscience.com/openproblems/NKSOpenProblems.pdf) which must surely contain many suitable candidates (although note some of the questions are more in History of Mathematics territory).  I'd be surprised if they've been all ticked off in the last decade.

Wolfram's opus also serves as some inspiration as to how simple systems with complex emergent behaviour can create an enormous - and accessible - fresh new landscape of problems ripe for exploration.

Comment: Your link the open problems appears to be broken.

Comment: Ooops!  Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat forgotten problem from Paul Erdős is proving his following conjecture:

Let $f(r)$ equal the maximum of the sum of the side lengths of $r$ squares inscribed in a unit square such that they have no interior points in common. Erdős conjectured: For any positive integer $k$, $$f(k^2+1)=k.$$

As far as I know, this is not proven.

Answer (score -1):

[Two envelopes problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_envelopes_problem)

From wikpedia:
The two envelopes problem, also known as the exchange paradox, is a brain teaser, puzzle, or paradox in logic, philosophy, probability, and recreational mathematics. It is of special interest in decision theory, and for the Bayesian interpretation of probability theory. Historically, it arose as a variant of the necktie paradox.

The problem:

> You have two indistinguishable envelopes that each contain money. One contains twice as much as the other. You may pick one envelope and keep the money it contains. You pick at random, but before you open the envelope, you are offered the chance to take the other envelope instead.

It can be argued that it is to your advantage to swap envelopes by showing that your expected return on swapping exceeds the sum in your envelope. This leads to the paradoxical conclusion that it is beneficial to continue to swap envelopes indefinitely.

Example -
Assume the amount in my selected envelope is \$20. If I happened to have selected the larger of the two envelopes, that would mean that the amount in my envelope is twice the amount in the other envelope. So in this case the amount in the other envelope would be \$10. However if I happened to have selected the smaller of the two envelopes, that would mean that the amount in the other envelope is twice the amount in my envelope. So in this second scenario the amount in the other envelope would be \$40. The probability of either of these scenarios is one half, since there is a 50% chance that I initially happened to select the larger envelope and a 50% chance that I initially happened to select the smaller envelope. The expected value calculation for how much money is in the other envelope would be the amount in the first scenario times the probability of the first scenario plus the amount in the second scenario times the probability of the second scenario, which is \$10 * 1/2 + \$40 * 1/2. The result of this calculation is that the expected value of money in the other envelope is \$25. Since this is greater than my selected envelope, it would appear to my advantage to always switch envelopes.

A large number of solutions have been proposed. The usual scenario is that one writer proposes a solution that solves the problem as stated, but then another writer discovers that altering the problem slightly revives the paradox. In this way, a family of closely related formulations of the problem have been created, which are discussed in the literature.
No proposed solution is widely accepted as correct. Despite this it is common for authors to claim that the solution to the problem is easy, even elementary. However, when investigating these elementary solutions they often differ from one author to the next. In the last two decades, several new papers have been published every year.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this an open problem myself, it's more like a problem which is open to multiple resolutions, some of which have already been discovered.

Comment: There is no probability distribution on a subset $A$ of the positive integers such a random variable $X$ can satisfy $\mathrm P(X=2n)=\mathrm P(X=n)$ for all $n\in A$.