# Integer solutions to the equation $a^3+b^3+c^3=30$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, computational-mathematics

The following problem was posed to me but I could not do much about it:

> Determine if there are any integer solutions to the equation
>   $a^3+b^3+c^3=30$

I made a computer search that shows that there are no integers $a,b,c$ such that $a^3+b^3+c^3=30$ and $|a|,|b|,|c|<51$

Thank you a lot.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2007-76-259/S0025-5718-07-01947-3/S0025-5718-07-01947-3.pdf

Comment: From Wolfram:
"... all numbers $N<1000$ and not of the form $9n \pm 4$ are known to be expressible as the sum

$N=A^3+B^3+C^3$ 

of three (positive or negative) cubes with the exception of $N=33, 42, 74, 114, 165, 390, 579, 627, 633, 732, 795, 906, 921$, and $975$ (Miller and Woollett 1955; Gardiner et al. 1964; Guy 1994, p. 151; Mishima; Elsenhaus and Jahnel 2007). Examples include

$30 = (-283059965)^3+(-2218888517)^3+2220422932^3$ ..."

Comment: @WillJagy - a great find!

Comment: Table 2 in the paper cited by Jagy above needs an update.

Comment: As of 2016, three solutions are now known for $N=30$, $$2220422932^3 - 283059965^3 - 2218888517^3 =30\\
3982933876681^3 - 636600549515^3 - 3977505554546^3 = 30\\ -662037799708799^3 + 190809268841284^3 + 656711689254565^3 = 30$$ with the last found by S. Huisman.

Comment: Didn’t *Beck et Al* find the first solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

($\color{red}{Update:}$ ***March 2019. The case $N=33$ has been found.***)

($\color{red}{Update:}$ ***September 2019. The case $N=42$ has been found.***)

The equation

$$x^3+y^3+z^3 = N$$

has been oft-discussed in both MSE and MO. For example, see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203957/decidability-of-x3y3z3-c), [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58188/are-nontrivial-integer-solutions-known-for-x3y3z3-3), and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-three-cubes-in-infinitely-many-ways).

Searching a low range $|x,y,z|$ just won't do. It's quite interesting to see how search ranges have increased over the years using ever more clever algorithms.

> **I. 1955**

Many $N\leqslant 100$ with search bound 3200.

J.C.P. Miller and M.F.C. Woollett. Solutions of the Diophantine Equation $x^3+y^3+z^3 = k$. J London Math Soc **30** (1955), p.111-113.

> **II. 1964**

$$4271^3 -4126^3 -1972^3=87$$

with search bound 65536.

V.L. Gardiner; R.B. Lazarus; P.R. Stein. [Solutions of the Diophantine Equation $x^3+y^3 = z^3 - d$](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1964-18-087/S0025-5718-1964-0175843-9/S0025-5718-1964-0175843-9.pdf). Mathematics of Computation, vol. 18, no. 87 (Jul 1964), pp.408-413.

> **III. 1992**

$$134476^3+ 117367^3 -159380^3 = 39$$

$$40500964^3+ 22894759^3-42805979^3 = 84$$

B. Conn and L. Vaserstein, "*[On sums of three integral cubes](http://www.math.psu.edu/vstein/113P.pdf)*". Penn State Department of Mathematics report PM 131 (1992). Contemporary Mathematics **166** (1994), p.285-294. MR1284068 (95g:11128)

> **IV. 1993**

$$134476^3+ 117367^3 -159380^3 = 39$$

D. Heath-Brown, W. Lioen, and H. Te Riele, "*[On Solving the Diophantine Equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=k$ on a Vector Computer](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/1528/1528D.pdf)*".

> **V. 1995**

$$-435203231^3 +435203083^3 +4381159^3 = 75$$

Andrew Bremner. "*On sums of three cubes*". Canadian Mathematical Society Conference Proceedings **15** (1995), p.87-91.

> **VI. 1999**

$$2220422932^3 -283059965^3 -2218888517^3 = 30$$

$$-61922712865^3+60702901317^3 +23961292454^3 = 52$$

Michael Beck, Eric Pine, Wayne Tarrant, and Kim Yarbrough Jensen (see p.18 of Noam  Elkies, "*Rational points near curves and small non-zero $|x^3-y^2|$ via lattice reduction*").

> **VII. 2001**

$$25585441403^3 + 47272468418^3 - 49649244505^3 = 834$$

with search bound $10^{11}$ found by [D.J. Bernstein](http://cr.yp.to/threecubes.html).

> **VIII. 2009**

$$2322626411251^3 + 19868127639556^3 - 19878702430997^3 =894$$

with search bound $10^{14}$ found by [A. Elsenhans and J. Jahnel](http://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/jahnel/Arbeiten/Liste/threecubes_20070419.txt).

> **IX. 2016**

$$66229832190556^3 + 283450105697727^3 −284650292555885^3 = 74$$

with search bound $10^{15}$ found by [S. Huisman](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07746).

> **X. Mar 2019**

$$8866128975287528^3 -8778405442862239^3 -2736111468807040^3 = 33$$

with search bound $10^{16}$ found by [Andrew Booker](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maarb/papers/cubesv1.pdf).

> **XI. Sep 2019**

$$-80538738812075974^3+80435758145817515^3+12602123297335631^3 = 42$$

found by [Andrew Booker at Bristol and Andrew Sutherland at MIT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyG8Vlw5aAw).

> **Papers**

In "*[New integer representations as the sum of three cubes](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2007-76-259/S0025-5718-07-01947-3/S0025-5718-07-01947-3.pdf)*" (2007) by Beck, Pine, Tarrant, and Yarbrough-Jensen they give a list of ***28*** $N<1000$ with no $x,y,z$ decomposition.

In "*[New sums of three cubes](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2009-78-266/S0025-5718-08-02168-6/S0025-5718-08-02168-6.pdf)*" by A. Elsenhans and J. Jahnel (2009) this has been reduced to just ***14*** unsolved $N$ (also quoted in *[Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicNumber.html)*) namely,

$$N = \color{red}{33, 42, 74}, 114, 165, 390, 579, 627, 633, 732, 795, 906, 921, 975$$

**Update:** Numbers in red have been solved, so there are now just ***11*** unsolved $N$. Hopefully, over the years, we can slowly complete this list.

**Note:** Relevant data are also given by [Leonid Durman](http://www.euler413.narod.ru/) (inc. $x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4 = z^4$), by [Mishima](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~KC2H-MSM/mathland/math04/cube01.htm), while other solutions can be found in Elsenhans and Jahnel's site.

Comment: You might want to update your table as [$N=74$ is solved.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07746)
$$
(-284650292555885)^3 + 66229832190556^3 + 283450105697727^3 = 74
$$

Comment: @YongHaoNg: Beautiful! Thanks. (This was found 2016 and I missed it.)

Comment: Just beautiful...

Comment: 33 is solved as well! $33=8866128975287528^3+(-8778405442862239)^3+(-2736111468807040)^3$

Comment: @mkocabas: Thanks! I'll update the table. Who found it?

Comment: Timothy Browning. Check: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/ayzy6s/33886612897528752838778405442862239327361114688070/

Comment: According to [Gil Kalai](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2019/03/09), credit for finding that solution for 33 is due to Andrew Booker. Booker documented the search in his paper [Cracking the Problem with 33](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maarb/papers/cubesv1.pdf).

Comment: @RosieF: Thanks. Has been corrected, and link added.

Comment: Could you clarify the year of discovery of that solution for 39? It's in a table in Martin Gardner. Knotted Doughnuts. Pub. Freeman. ISBN 0-7167-1799-9 (pbk). ch. 18, p.228--229. My copy gives the publication year as 1986; is that wrong? (Of course it might be that the 1st edition was published in 1986 and my copy is of a revised edition, but then I'd expect it to state its own publication year correctly.) That chapter in Gardner cites Gardiner, Lazarus & Stein's articles from 1964 & 1973 but nothing later.

Comment: @RosieF. I've looked again at Heath-Brown et al's [1993 paper](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/1528/1528D.pdf) and they explicitly say they found the first solution for $N=39$. And I looked at Lazarus et al's [1964 paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1964-18-087/S0025-5718-1964-0175843-9/S0025-5718-1964-0175843-9.pdf). Their range was only about 66,000, so they couldn't have found $N=39$ back then. So the possibility is that your copy of Gardner's _Knotted Doughnuts_ is not the 1986 first printing.

Comment: @RosieF: Gardner in p. 229 of Knotted Doughnuts remarks _"Some were not easy to come by, notably the expression for 87 in which each cube has four digits."_ I find it strange that he makes this remark, while ignoring 39 in the same table with solutions of ***six digits***. It's almost as if 39 was added later.