# Solve $x^5 + y^5 + z^5 = 2015$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, open-problem

If $x, y, z$ are integer numbers, solve:

$$x^5 + y^5 + z^5 = 2015$$

A friend of mine claims there is no known solution, and, at the same time, *there is no proof that there is no solution*, but I do not believe him. However, I wasn't able to make much progress disproving his claim.

I tried modular arithmetics, but couldn't reach useful conclusion.

Comment: Brute force should be possible, after all they can't go above 4.

Comment: You should be aware that the similar problem for cubes is not generally known; there is no congruence obstruction for $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 33,$ but no solution is known. This allows the variables positive or negative or zero, otherwise it is a finite check to decide if there is a solution with all variables positive or, say, non-negative.

Comment: It is well possible that no solution exists, and there is no way to prove this. Hilberts tenth problem was : Given a diophantic equation, can it be decided if it has a solution ? In general, this is not possible.

Comment: @Feyre These kinds of problems admit negative integers as part of the solution set, so brute force is not an option.

Comment: @user236182 You can play the same game modulo a power of $5$ or a prime that is $1$ mod $5$, since $5$ will divide the order of the multiplicative group, limiting potential values of $n^5$. I checked $25,11,31,41,61,71$ and there's no relief for $a=2015$.

Comment: If anyone cares to program searches, congruence relations _can_ be used to speed up the search. For instance, examining the equation mod $25$ allows you to conclude one of the numbers must be $1$ mod $5$ and the other two must be $2$ mod $5$.

Comment: And mod $11$, one must be $0$ with the other two among $\{1,3,4,5,9\}$. And mod $31$, one must be $0$, with a more complicated restriction on the other two, etc.

Comment: @alex.jordan
Yeah, I was being sloppy, though this is why I prefer it when it explicitly says with $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$

I realized it when it was too late to edit.

Comment: @Feyre Hmm, I'm not sure that you took me meaning. I meant, for starters, that if you wanted to program a brute force search, you wouldn't need to run through triplets $(x,y,z)$ up to some cap on absolute value. Instead you could run through triplets $(1+5k,2+5m,2+5n)$, cutting the search over the same bound down to $\frac1{125}$ as big. And more complications from other modular relations would cut it down even more.

Comment: @alex.jordan
I responded to your other comment, not that one. Regardless, bridge, water.

Comment: @alex.jordan What about $101, 125, 131, 151, 181, 191$?

Comment: @VividD I didn't check. As these numbers get larger the chances this would help get smaller. The values of $n^5$ make up one fifth of the residues. Then when you start looking at sums of three of them, the possible sums start to cover a higher and higher proportion of all residues, ruling out fewer and fewer cases.

Comment: @alex.jordan Right, don't bother with that than. It looks it is not a promising path... Thanks anyway for your info so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question doesn't mention signs, then equivalently,

$$x^n+y^n = z^n+\beta$$

This is what Noam Elkies calls a *[Fermat near-miss](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/ferm.html)* and he has a table for $n\leq20$. It is interesting to ask: Let $xyz\neq0$. *For a given $n$, how small can $\beta$ get?*

> For $n=3$:

It is well-known that $\beta =1$. (And it has an infinite number of integer solutions.)

> For $n=5$:

It seems it is $\beta = 12$,

$$13^5+16^5=17^5+12$$

D. Stork's search showed there is no $\beta =2015$ with $|x|,|y|,|z|\leq200$. We can extend that with Elkies' tables (which go as high as $8\; million$). Excluding $|x|,|y|,|z|<17$, the next smallest $|\beta|$ with $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$ are,

$$\begin{aligned}
&42^5 + 71^5 = 72^5 + 2951\\
&104^5 + 133^5 = 140^5-75083\\
&133^5 + 228^5 = 231^5-87890\\
&\quad\vdots\\
&707902^5 + 5645541^5 = 5645576^5+39515947850357
\end{aligned}$$

So $\beta=2015$ has missed the train, and the chances it exists is very remote.

Comment: **P.S.** We can wait a few more centuries until the year $2951$ comes.  :)

Answer (score 6):

These problems are usually done allowing the variables to have mixed signs, some positive, some negative or zero.

i think I will make this an answer. The similar problem for sums of three cubes has been worked on by many people; as of the linked article, the smallest number for which there are no congruence obstructions but no known expression is $$ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 33.  $$

See [THIS for the size of numbers involved](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2007-76-259/S0025-5718-07-01947-3/S0025-5718-07-01947-3.pdf). Indeed, on the seventh page, they give a list of numbers up to 1000 still in doubt, starts out 33, 42, 74, 156...

I see nothing wrong with suggesting that your problem could be in the same unsettled state, plus I do not think as many people have worked on the sum of three fifth powers.

Comment: Elkies has done work on $x^n+y^n = z^n+\beta$. Kindly see my answer below.

Comment: "Cracking the problem with 33". https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386034/integer-solutions-to-the-equation-a3b3c3-30/1565427#1565427

Answer (score 2):

A very quick exhaustive computer search (for $0 \le x, y, z \leq \lceil 2015^.2 \rceil = 5$) shows there is no solution, as does a search with $0 \le x \le 200$ and $-200 \le y, z, \le 200$.

Comment: that's fine, and I am not sure the person asking is aware of the significance, bu the problem changes dramatically if we allow the variables to have mixed signs; this is what is usually done.

Comment: I see, you edited in a search with mixed signs. Good.