# Integer solutions to the diophantine equation $a^3+b^3+c^3=6$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, computational-mathematics

I once thought that this equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=6$ has only a few smaller integer solutions. Until somebody told me this $6=192722201207819^3+162765491944499^3+(-225522344776678)^3$ existed. I don't know how it came about.

**Question**: How to find more integer solutions to the equation $a^3+b^3+c^3={\color{red}{6}}$?

> **a few smaller integer solutions**:
>   \begin{align*} 
> (-637)^3+(-205)^3+644^3&=6\\ 
> (-235)^3+(-55)^3+236^3&=6\\ 
> (-58)^3+(-43)^3+65^3&=6\\ 
> (-1)^3+(-1)^3+2^3&=6\\ 
> \end{align*}

Something happened recently

I've also heard that mathematicians have recently solved this problem:

The least integer solutions to the equation $a^3+b^3+ c^3=33$

[Triple cubic Diophantine equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386034)

[42 is the new 33 - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASoz_NuIvP0)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @YuiToCheng Sorry, I didn't make it clear. It has been added now.

Comment: First of all, the fact that a similar question was solved for $33$ seems to be irrelevant. (Unless the opposite is proved) Secondly, What did you try?

Comment: The [sums of three cubes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes) is open.  It is unclear whether your interest is limited to ways of expressing six (as the body of the Question suggests) or about the broad family of problems (as your links and closing remarks hint at).

Answer (score 3):

Nothing more than brute force computation I'm afraid.

The method used to crack $33$ was to rearrange to $$(a^2-ab+b^2)=\frac{33-c^3}{a+b}$$
The computer can then assign a random $c$ and test all values of $a,b$ such that $(a+b)|(33-c^3)$ which requires much less testing, but still very large amounts.